# DatePickerCellEditor date selection is not working

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable to which I added a DatePickerCellEditor to edit dates by overriding the getCellEditor method for the table. When i edit this cell by typing on the text box everything works fine and the data is changed. Unfortunately, when I press the button and select a date from the calendar, the calendar disappears, but the date does not change.

Here is my getCellEditor. Is there something wrong with it, or is it something else? I'm using JDK 8. Thank you.

```
@Override
    public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
        TableCellEditor ret;
        //column = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);        
        if ((column == 1 || column == 2) && getModel().getValueAt(row, column) != null) {
            Class rowClass = getModel().getValueAt(row, column).getClass();            
            if (rowClass.equals(Integer.class)) {
                return new SpinnerCellEditor();
            } else if (rowClass.equals(Date.class)) {
                return new DatePickerCellEditor();
            } else {
                return getDefaultEditor(rowClass);
            }
        } else {
            return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been the terminateEditOnFocusLost property on the table. It seemed that it forced the DatePickerCellEditor to close editing before receiving the update from the calendar popup.

I just commented the following line from the code that was configuring the JTable and it started working properly.

```
listaFiltragem.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```